Google slides iframe background color
When I embed the iframe on a WordPress Elementor page, the background color appears black.
Follow the iframe link:
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTlFXw8upfjVRFAzq6SZM9Me3YT54q-WowMs80MQYSP924mEr8vg3EnAOSz4o_vNSN_qWskDDcbqmt0/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&headers=false&rm=minimal" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="false" mozallowfullscreen="false" webkitallowfullscreen="false"></iframe>
The iframe renders as follows:

I tried to change the color in WordPress, but I think the problem is with the iframe.
I expect the background to appear white, the same as the page.
